# Sharing a single connection to mongo db between all celery workers

Tags: python, flask, singleton, celery, pymongo

I have a series of celery workers which carry out tasks, stored using REDIS; in particular I have three categories of workers which respectively carry out three categories of tasks. The tasks belonging to each of these categories require access to a mongo DB. For reasons of efficiency I would like to use a single connection to the DB to be used by all workers. So far I've tried both passing as argument to "send_task" the connection in the following way:

```
myclient = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
celeryWorker.send_task('tasks.beampolyline', myclient)
```

but clearly it returns as error that the object is not JSON serializable; both trying to share the myclient object among all the workers but with poor results. Any idea ? I feel I am very close to the solution but I am stuck on both approaches I am trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to define module level connection. Suppose `worker.py` as your worker module:

```
from mongodb import MongoClient

shared_connection = MongoClient()

@app.task(...)
def task(self, a, b):
    ...  # use shared_connection inside task
    return
```

In this solution, connection is shared between threads/processes of this worker.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but in that case wouldn't I have a connection for each type of task? Therefore having 3 types of task in practice I would have 3 of connections to the db. I would like to have a unique one that can be shared among all tasks/workers, basically a singleton approach

Comment: You can define all workers in a module. Connection is established in module importing. So, only one connection is established and shared between instances of all workers in a module.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible for me to do, I have to keep the various workers in modules in separate files. Is there really no way to do this with such an organization ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something similar?:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask import *

client = pymongo.MongoClient("yourcredentials")
db = client['ALLWORKER']
worker_1 = db['worker1']
worker_2 = db['worker_2']
```